# Apt-get command not found in docker

Tags: java, docker, java-17

I am trying to create a docker container with open jdk 17 but I get the following error: `/bin/sh: apt-get: command not found` . This is happenign since I changed the jdk version, before was working with: `adoptopenjdk:11-jdk` but unfortunately there is no 17 version for it.
Below my docker file:

```
   FROM openjdk:17  as builder
WORKDIR application
ARG JAR_FILE=backend/build/libs/backend-*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM openjdk:17  as runtime
WORKDIR application
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install fontconfig ttf-dejavu
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./

EXPOSE 8080
ENV _JAVA_OPTIONS "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true - Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xverify:none - Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=16"
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp",".:BOOT-INF/lib/*:BOOT-INF/classes:/META-INF", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Comment: Hi, maybe this could help: [link](https://forums.docker.com/t/openjdk-bin-sh-apt-command-not-found/72606). They encountered a pretty similar issue, it was because the openjdk container was to minimalistic

Comment: `apt-get` is only available in debian or ubuntu based containers; why would you assume that it is available in the openjdk container? The openjdk container is based on oracle linux and uses the `microdnf` command to manage packages.

Comment: @larsks thanks for the answer. Which one I could use,for java17 ubuntu or debian?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. You're using the "openjdk" container for java, and you can use `microdnf` to install packages.

Comment: I would like to use another jdk distribution that allows to use apt-get. Previously I used adoptopenjdk:11-jdk but there is no 17 version. Can you suggest one?

Comment: The AdoptOpenJDK project was renamed to Eclipse Adoptium a few **years** ago, and its images are called [`eclipse-temurin`](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin/). That said, I don't know if these images provide `apt-get` (though they seem to be Ubuntu based, as were the AdoptOpenJDK images, so I guess they do).

Comment: Let's say that it does not contain apt-get, how can I add it to my docker file?

Answer (score 1):

For the second stage of your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt update -q && \
    apt install -y -q openjdk-17-jre openjdk-17-jdk-headless && \
    apt install -y -q fontconfig fonts-dejavu
```

Using the `ubuntu:22.04` base image will give you access to `apt`. You just need to install the required JDK stuff explicitly now.

I replaced `ttf-dejavu` with `fonts-dejavu` since the package appears to have been renamed.